# ¿Cómo paso variables desde el cliente (javascript) hasta el servidor nodejs (express)?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, backend

Estoy intentando pasar variables de lado del cliente hacia el servidor. Lo que intento es, por ejemplo, que yo tenga una función prompt()

```
var n = prompt("Elige un numero");
```

cuyo resultado se guarde en la variable n, y esta pase al backend. He buscado en google pero solo me aparece la operación inversa, osea, pasarlo del backend al frontend, y eso no es lo que busco.

Comment: se deberia usar ajax

Comment: Mandar algo al servidor implica hacer una petición HTTP, ya sea AJAX o mediante un formulario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes pasarlo atravez de una peticion:

**Cliente(usando jquery):**

```
var n = prompt("Elige un numero");
$.ajax({
  url: '/mi_ruta',
  type: "POST",
  data: {numero:n}

}).done(function(data){
   alert("El numero mas uno es: "+data)
})
```

**Servidor:**

```
const express=require('express'),
      app = express()

 app.post('/mi_ruta',(req,res) =>{
   let num = req.body.numero //aqui viene el data de la peticion , con el numero en la variable numero
    num++ //lo incrementas
    res.send(num) //lo envias a la peticion incrementado , 
                   //o podrias hacer cualquier cosa con el numero y 
                   //hacer algun render de alguna plantilla con el numero
 })
```

> Nota: Si deseas realizar las peticiones sin utilizar `jquery` , te dejo estos dos ejemplos, [uno](http://programacionextrema.com/2016/08/15/ajax-sin-jquery-sin-librerias/) [dos](http://whk.elhacker.net/index.php?topic=9.0) , son ejemplos aplicativos , pero te aconsejo utilizar la variante con `ajax` que es muy eficiente en cuanto a peticiones , ademas de que se encuentra implementada en forma de promesa brindándote muchas mas funcionalidades.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ¿Existe alguna forma sin tener que utilizar ajax o jquery?

Comment: ya te edite la respuesta, indicándote la documentación si no deseas utilizar `ajax`

Comment: Me sirvió mucho. De hecho, lo que estoy intentando hacer es, que el usuario cree carpetas en el servidor desde el cliente, usando File System de NodeJS. Entonces, lo que estoy intentando hacer con el tema de las variables, es que el usuario ingrese un string con el path para que luego con la funcion mkdir se cree la carpeta dependiendo del path que este le puso.

Comment: bueno utilízalo así mismo como te lo di , en el server en vez de guardar el numero , manda el string , pásaselo al fs y en el cliente , cámbialo para que mandes el string

Comment: Muchas gracias paisano, saludos a cubita la bella, estamos en contacto.

Answer (score 0):

Uhi, dejame decirte de buena manera que estas perdido. 
Para empezar, toda conexión que hagas externamente hacia un servidor, cualquiera sea, recibirá información en forma de cadenas. No hay tal cosa como pasar una variable de un cliente a un servidor. En todo caso lo que pasas de un lado al otro es una cadena de "texto" y allí lo procesas ya actúas en consecuencia. 
Lo que quieres hacer no es complicado, pero primero debes establecer que protocolo de comunicación vas a usar (TCP / UDP / HTTP), yo eligiría HTTP. 
Luego, debes entender como funciona HTTP, averigua puntualmente que son las cabeceras y el cuerpo de una solicitud HTTP. 
Por último implementa ajax en tu cliente y un servidor HTTP en nodejs para comenzar a recibir y procesar la información. Una vez que llegue el "request"
 al servidor podrás actuar en consecuencia de los parámtros que hallas enviado. Te recomiendo escribir los cuerpos de HTTP en JSON tanto para recibir comandos como para enviar respuestas al cliente. Deberás utilizar las funciones JSON.parse() y JSON.stringfy() 
Espero que te sirva de guía.

Comment: Gracias hermano, si, se que se pasa con una petición mediante HTTP, preferiblemente una petición POST para que viaje por el cuerpo de la página. Lo que no sabía si se podían pasar las variables por ahí, ya me explicaron más arriba como era, y si,concuerdo contigo en que se pasa una cadena de texto, en realdiad, eso es lo que quiero. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta hermano. Saludos.