# "Enviar" variable de java script a node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

espero me puedan ayudar, quiero "enviar" una variable de un documento de java script a node js, documento java script:

```
var nombre = "Juan";
```

Documento en node.js

```
    'use strict'

    var app = require('express')(),


    http = require('http').createServer(app),

    //Se inicializ  a el modulo socket.io
    io = require('socket.io')(http),


    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    publicDir = `${__dirname}/public`


    http.listen(port, () => {
        console.log('Escuchando desde el puerto2 :' , port )
    })

//Aqui quiero imprimir la variable que esta en el doc de js por ejemplo:
console.log(nombre);
```

Comment: Mira en esta pregunta, seguro que te puede servir: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/138194/c%C3%B3mo-paso-variables-desde-el-cliente-javascript-hasta-el-servidor-nodejs-exp

Comment: Muy bien , lo voy a checar, gracias  por responder :D

Comment: Hmm, puedes utilizar la funcion **fetch** que ya viene por defecto en los navegadores más o menos decentes.

Comment: Ok , lo voy a checar muchas gracias :D